# Combining value 'A' to 'B' to form one value as C

Tags: r

I'm working in R and wanted to combine values as follows:

I have two variables that I've created,

```
a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(4,5,6)
```

and I would like to now make a new value 'c' that would have an output:

```
c

 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

My question is how one would do this in R? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If `c()` can combine `1` `2` and `3` like `c(1,2,3)`, then how would you combine `a` and `b`?

Comment: @thelatemail much as I like your approach to answer such a simple q with a hint (+1), perhaps better to do one of two things more in line with SO philosophy: Either answer the question (for benefit of beginners), or flag to close the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

here is the easiest way to do it

```
a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(4,5,6)

c <- c(a,b)

c
```

Even though it is unnecessary, you could also write a function that does it for you

```
function_to_combine_vectors <- function(vector_1, vector_2){
new_vector <- c(vector_1, vector_2)
return(new_vector)
}
c <- function_to_combine_vectors(a, b)
print(c)
```

Comment: But you overwrote the `c()` function by assigning a variable named `c`.